# Is there a way to bind the ref {useRef} to the submit function/variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react and I'm trying to build a form. I want the page to redirect to the home page once the form is submitted.  Is there a way to set useRef to watch the in-built submit function?
I currently have no compiler errors but the page won't redirect.

current code:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
export default function Form() {
    const submit = useRef(false)
    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
    const redir = (data) => {
        console.log(submit.current)
        console.log(data)
            return <Redirect to='/' />
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form className="form" ref={submit} onSubmit={handleSubmit(redir)}>
```

Comment: Looks like you've past not whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning the `Redirect` from a handler function but you need to render it. Instead, you could use `history.push('/')` to do what you want.

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

//...

export default function Form() {
  const submit = useRef(false);
  const history = useHistory();
  const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
  const redir = (data) => {
    console.log(submit.current);
    console.log(data);
    history.push('/');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="form" ref={submit} onSubmit={handleSubmit(redir)}>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```